# How to Insert mutiple values in database with same column ID using Entity FrameWork

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am doing Canteen management system project in that I want to insert with one order ID I should insert multiple items in sql database.

I am getting each food item as one order id but I want to get multiple food items as each order ID.

Comment: Is this a school project? Also, what kind of system is this? (Desktop/web?) We need more info to help you here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use EntityFramework or LinqToSQL, you can get items with this code:

```
var ItemsOfOrder = from n in Orders
where n.id = 1231
select n.Items

foreach(var Item in ItemsOfOrder)
{
   Print(Item);
}
```

Multiple insert:

Crete an order and multiple items.
Then add Items to Order's navigation property (navigation to Items)

```
Order ord = new Order();

Item item1 = new Item();
Item item2 = new Item();
Item item3 = new Item();

ord.Items.Add(item1);
ord.Items.Add(item2);
ord.Items.Add(item3);

DbContext db = new DbContext();
db.Orders.Add(ord);
db.SaveChanges;
```

Comment: I want to insert multiple items with same Order Id When I clicking on Submit Button.

Comment: I want to insert multiple items with same Order Id When I clicking on Submit Button. When We click button ,it should insert multiple items With one Order Id. when Click on Again Submit Button It should Generate new Order Id To insert multiple values.

Comment: i want to insert into database with multiple items by selecting checkboxs In one Order id.Not to retriving .